# How is root directory mounted on Arch?

Tags: archlinux, mount, fstab

I installed Arch Linux ARM for Raspberry Pi and it doesn't have an entry for the root directory in `/etc/fstab` but it's still mounted on boot somehow. How is it mounted and how can mount options be modified for it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

While I don't have Arch Linux to check if this, it's probably mounted by kernel itself and never remounted. You can check your `/proc/cmdline` and you should see something like `root=/dev/mmcblk0p2` and `rootfstype=ext4` options. You can set them in `/boot/cmdline.txt` file. First one specifies which device (partition) should be mounted as root device, second one specifies filesystem type. 
If you want to change some mount options, you can use `rootflags=` kernel option - just specify proper mount option string (for example `rootflags=data=writeback,acl`).

*Note* that you can only specify filesystem specific options like this, filesystem independent options seems not to be working.

*Also note* that if you make an error setting this option, your system wont boot. In order to fix this you have to use emergency boot or change your `/boot/cmdline.txt` file on other computer.

You can also remount your root file system somewhere in the boot process with following command:

```
mount -o remount,data=ordered /
```

Comment: You're spot on. Suppose I'd like to add several options, in what format should they be listed?

Comment: @seron: The same format you use for `mount` command, comma delimited, no spaces. Take a look at the modified example in my answer.

Comment: Thank you. I tried rootflags=noatime but it failed to boot. Anyway, you've answered my original question and I feel grateful for that.

Comment: (I can't comment your last comment because I don't have reputation).
I had the same idea as you about noatime. But now relatime is the default behavior and since noatime seems not to be "a good" optimization.

Comment: About rootflags=noatime failing. I experienced the same problem; see this SO question: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/130966/kernel-panic-when-passing-noatime-in-bootargs